# Уместно ли тире в данном случае?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, деепричастия

**Получить этот иммунитет можно и естественным путём — переболев, но цена за него может быть слишком велика.**

Answer (score 1):

Уместно, потому что после тире подставляется "то есть".

Правило Розенталя такое:
Перед пояснительным членом предложения обычно стоят слова *именно, а именно, **то есть*** (при отсутствии в предложении эти слова могут быть вставлены). При отсутствии пояснительного союза вместо запятой перед пояснительным членом предложения часто ставится тире:
*Эти птицы [стенолазы] добывают свой корм исключительно в воздухе — питаются летающими насекомыми.

Он обладает особой способностью — всё делать вовремя.

Разговор шёл один — о погоде.

Профессия его была самая мирная — учитель.

На выполнение работы потребовалось меньше, чем мы ожидали, — два месяца.*
http://www.old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119