# Уточнение или сложное существительное

Tags: запятые, дефис

Помогите, пожалуйста, со знаками препинания в предложении:
Бухгалтерам (?) клиентам компании (?) доступна новая услуга: бесплатные консультации.
"Бухгалтер - клиент" - это сложное существительное и нужно писать через дефис? Или "клиентам компании" - это уточнение и нужно обособит оборот запятыми?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уточнение так лучше не делать, оно не звучит и совпадает по пунктуации с приложением, смысл которого описан ниже. Уточнение, которое выглядит как приложение, не используется.
Это основная информация (то, что нужно быть клиентом), такое в уточнение не кидается. И уточнения не используются в объявлениях и деловом стиле.

Если нужно дефисом присоединить фразу (*клиенты компании*), то вместо него ставится тире.
http://orthographia.ru/orf.php?paragraph=pp154.php
Получается так:
*Бухгалтерам — {клиентам компании} доступна новая услуга: бесплатные консультации.*
Примеры Розенталя:
*На Совещании Политического Консультативного Комитета государств — участников Варшавского Договора о дружбе, сотрудничестве и взаимной помощи была принята Декларация.

В столице нашей родины — Москве состоялся VI Международный фестиваль молодежи и студентов.

Комсомольцы — учащиеся старших классов решили активно включиться в работу по уборке
урожая.

Коммунист — работник государственного аппарата должен служить образцом для других.

Вот так и познакомились почтовый работник — северянка Валентина Быстрова с Николаем Ухабовым.*

Надо отметить, что применение двоеточия нестандартное, но интонация понижения (что характерна для двоеточия) там звучит.

Смысл такой:
*Бухгалтерам, клиентам компании, доступна...* || Вне контекста это означает, что все бухгалтеры в мире — клиенты компании.
*Нашим бухгалтерам, клиентам компании, доступна...* || Это означает, что все бухгалтеры компании — её клиенты.
*Бухгалтерам — клиентам компании доступна...* || Тем бухгалтерам, что клиенты кампании. Нужный смысл.

Comment: 1. Почему же бухгалтеры не обязательно клиенты этой компании? Здесь как раз речь про бухгалтеров, которые именно клиенты данной компании. То есть услуга для бухгалтеров, которые клиенты именно этой компании.
2. Вы имеете в виду тире после "новая услуга"?

Comment: 1. Потому что не все бухгалтеры станут клиентами. Или они должны быть клиентами в обязательном порядке? 2. Да, обычно ставят тире, но здесь звучит с двоеточием.

Comment: 1. Обращение идет именно к бухгалтерам, которые уже клиенты. К другим не обращаемся. То есть прочитают бухгалтеры, которые уже являются клиентами. 2. Тоже сомневалась с двоеточием. Но не из-за интонации поставила двоеточие, можно же заменить "а именно". Вроде бы в таких случаях ставится тире.

Comment: *Обращение идет именно к бухгалтерам, которые уже клиенты* — это сразу было понятно. Постановка тире вместо дефиса этому соответствует, но об этом правиле знают единицы (из-за этого могут не понять либо заподозрить ошибку). Разбираться с этим предложением полезно для обучения, углубления знаний (часто вопросы задаются с этой целью), но если его нужно применить где-то, то нужна правка.

Comment: При тире тоже можно подставить "а именно": https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/468040

Comment: Прошу прощения, не поняла. Вы пишите: "его нужно применить где-то, то нужна правка". Не совсем понимаю, о какой правке речь. Поставить запятые?

Comment: Нет, переделать предложение как-то.